# How to decompile a exe file made by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyc, pyz

a desktop.exe made by pyinstaller.  I want to decomplie it. I extracted it with pyinstxtractor.py.  and  ran desktop.pyc.there are some errors : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxx'.  I think that the mudules are compressed in PYZ-00.pyz.  I ran PYZ-00.pyz and got some error:SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xcb' in file.

How to decompress the PYZ-00.pyz? Should I decompress it? How to run desktop.pyc correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to decompile it ?